# How to check if string A "contains" B in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 strings , let's suppose stringA and stringB . I want to know if stringA contains stringB. Since I am new to SQL Server and T SQL. I am not sure what prebuild function can I use .

It should be something like this.

```
If (contains(stringA,stringB))
```

then Print `'It Contains it'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StringA VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @StringB VARCHAR(100)

SET @StringA = 'ABCDEF'
SET @StringB= 'CD'


IF @StringA LIKE '%' + @StringB + '%' 
    Print 'It Contains it'
ELSE
    PRINT 'It doesn''t'

SET @StringA = 'ABCDEF'
SET @StringB= 'WU'


IF @StringA LIKE '%' + @StringB + '%' 
    Print 'It Contains it'
ELSE
    PRINT 'It doesn''t'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
SELECT t.* FROM dbo.Table t
WHERE stringA LIKE '%' + @stringB + '%'
```

or with an `IF`:

```
IF @stringA LIKE '%' + @stringB + '%' PRINT 'It contains it'
ELSE PRINT 'It does not contain it';
```

Answer (score 1):

1-

```
if CHARINDEX('ME','MEMOZA') > 0
begin
    PRINT 'TRUE'
end
```

2- As suggested by Giannis Paraskevopulos

```
IF 'MEMOZA' LIKE '%' + 'MO' + '%' 
    Print 'It Contains it'
ELSE
    PRINT 'It doesn''t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me throw in the actual T-SQL [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) keyword, just for good measure, IF you are going to check for column content.